# externalize hibernate queries or sql queries in properties file in spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am developing Web Application in Spring and Hibernate in my eclipse.
I want to store my Hibernate queries or Sql queries in properties file and later use it in DAO.
Please let me know how to do this?
I am using generic DAO , is there any way to make generic queries?
Later i would like to store other things like pages links,title also in properties file.

So basically three interrelated questions.

Since I could not think of any way to make generic queries So i have overridden  findAll() method in concrete class.

I am using

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:properties/database.properties"/>
```

to load the properties.But the problem is how to use it to get hql in java code or class files?

DAO

```
public abstract class AbstractHibernateDAO<T extends Serializable> {

    public Class<T> clazz;//class object reference

    protected SessionFactory mysessionFactory;

public void setClazz(final Class<T> clazzToSet) {
        this.clazz = clazzToSet;
    }

protected Session getCurrentSession() {

        return mysessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return getCurrentSession().createQuery("from " + clazz.getName()).list();
    }
```

My concerete DAO

```
@Repository("categDAO")
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS,value="request")
public class CategoryDAO extends AbstractHibernateDAO<category_pojo>{

    public CategoryDAO() {

        setClazz(category_pojo.class);
    }

    @Override
    public category_pojo findOneByName(String name) {
        return (category_pojo) getCurrentSession().createQuery("from "+clazz.getName()+" where categoryName=:name").setParameter("name",name).uniqueResult();

    }


}
```

Comment: Have you seen how to use @Value in spring.. ? Check this:http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html

Comment: @value is used to initialize variable what i am trying to achieve is different.for example take this private @Value("${xprnOffset}") int expirationOffset;

Comment: Would you be willing to hard-code the queries in the properties file.?

Comment: what i am trying to achieve is placing queries in external files.so that it could be used by other users without accessing the code.

Comment: Alright. So basically what you would have to do is create a .properties file like : 

`SELECT_QUERY : select * from table`. Access the  query from your DAO like 

`@VALUE['propertyBean("SELECT_QUERY")']
 public String Select_Query`

Pass the query with the created String. All you need to go is create a property bean. Check here for reference: http://blog.csanchez.org/2005/06/30/spring-creating-a-bean-of-type-java-util-properties/

Comment: I am not able to understand the purpose of propertyBean.I can directly use @Value("${select_query}") String Select_query; what are we trying to achieve through propertybean?correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, it sounds like regular Spring usage.

You may have a class like:

```
class userDao {

    String findActiveUsers;
    //... Getters and Setters

    public List<User> findActiveUsers() {
        return getCurrentSession().createQuery(findActiveUsers).list();
    }
}
```

So, your application context would look like:

```
<bean id="userDao" class="my.package.UserDao">
    <property name="findActiveUsers" value="FROM User u WHERE u.active=true"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: This seems to be an alternate way.but I believe it  should not be used in my case because my purpose is not to touch the class file(DAO) or bean configuration file(application context).I want to externalize the queries in .properties file.

Comment: Externalizing to a property file is easily achieved with: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-properties

Comment: It is going to be way harder to achieve your goal if you can not change the application context and the DAO...

Comment: I am using <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:properties/database.properties"/> to load the properties.But the problem is how to use it to get hql in java code or class files?